# Show population count over time given start and end date

Tags: vega-lite

I have set of membership records that show a start date and and end date.

Here is an extract:

```
id,start_date,end_date
2759,2010-10-19,2016-10-31
2760,2010-10-19,2014-03-31
2761,2010-10-19,2023-03-31
2762,2010-10-21,2012-10-31
2763,2010-10-23,2015-11-30
2764,2010-10-24,2012-10-31
2765,2010-10-25,2012-10-30
2766,2010-10-30,2012-10-31
2767,2018-09-19,2019-10-18
```

I'm looking to encode this data with yearmonth along the x and count along the y based on the number of records that were a member in each particular yearmonth.

In case the above isn't clear, another example would be "given a data set that has the birth and death date of individuals in population, how do I create a chart that that shows population growth / decline each year".

It seems like you would want to have a conditional count if start_date <= yearmonth && end_date >=yearmonth but I'm not sure how I would express this in vega-lite json.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with a fold transform, followed by a calculate transform, followed by a window transform. Here's an example with some generated numerical data ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJMYgE7xkDsANFIQHbRkCcAXzZVqterCZkALB0jdeqAGxCRGMY2ao+s+WQCMABhXUadDfx099AZmMn1EzWAOWFYKXdFnH012WXCJmjekqgunFaoAEyeaiFO4XKRYLaB9vG+EW4AHLGm4qEpfkoCqgC6VHaQ8AywXMQAZgD2DAC2ZJRezbhu5Bl+ZbG0AMZ4w-i4CIRkMAj4rQB0ANaEAJ5gALwbYADkBfA7YAD8YHpgqAC0epCysKSokLDQ0IS8Q6qYAO4AljxNnx1aE0AA4zYjzG5QBrfQg9GZPF68W73KDwJqIXCQARlNLUOgtJzkWjQ2FubB4IhYirUUoQHFUSCtCRLGa4X7TNJJYZNaC-ADmZHQGEgAA9BdVVsDpg8AI74Orwb6IRVYDlQmFwh44AjTWKQVbi+CS6VQOUKpUIb6qyGQEma1HovBYyogARAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"start": 7, "end": 9},
      {"start": 4, "end": 6},
      {"start": 9, "end": 10},
      {"start": 9, "end": 13},
      {"start": 0, "end": 4},
      {"start": 4, "end": 6},
      {"start": 0, "end": 2},
      {"start": 0, "end": 3},
      {"start": 4, "end": 8},
      {"start": 3, "end": 6}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["start", "end"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.key == 'start' ? 1 : -1", "as": "added"},
    {
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "added", "as": "total"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "value"}]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "total"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just wanted to say thanks! - this was really helpful!! I have got sidetracked by another couple of projects but will come back to this soon.